# Can a Shared Lock Wait for a Shared Lock to complete?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am getting some deadlock exception on my server. I was able to grab some extended events log,

```
<resource-list>
    <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="89158" dbid="5" subresource="FULL" objectname="DB.dbo.Products" id="lock2fba9b780" mode="SIX" associatedObjectId="72057594050445312">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process2f64a3868" mode="S" requestType="wait" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process2f6986cf8" mode="S" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </pagelock>
    <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="89158" dbid="5" subresource="FULL" objectname="DB.dbo.Products" id="lock2fba9b780" mode="SIX" associatedObjectId="72057594050445312">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process2f64a3868" mode="S" requestType="wait" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process2f6987c38" mode="S" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </pagelock>
    <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="89158" dbid="5" subresource="FULL" objectname="DB.dbo.Products" id="lock2fba9b780" mode="SIX" associatedObjectId="72057594050445312">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process2f6c9e928" mode="SIX" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process2f64a3868" mode="S" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </pagelock>
    <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="86733" dbid="5" subresource="FULL" objectname="DB.dbo.Products" id="lock2f200fa80" mode="SIU" associatedObjectId="72057594050445312">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process2f6987c38" mode="S" />
        <owner id="process2f6986cf8" mode="S" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process2f6c9e928" mode="IX" requestType="convert" />
      </waiter-list>
    </pagelock>
  </resource-list>
```

Seeing the log it seems a Shared lock is waiting for Shared Lock to complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from the following image:

[image]

the process/session who generates this deadlock is `process2f6c9e928`.

1) This process has an SIX lock on page `5:1:89158` (DB:FILEID:PAGENUM) and require/waits for a IX lock on page `5:1:86733` (DB:FILEID:PAGENUM). But page `5:1:86733` is already locked by `process2f6986cf8` & `process2f6987c38` because they have S locks. SIX (existing) and S (requested) locks are incompatible (see bellow compatibility matrix).

2) The following processes: `process2f6986cf8` & `process2f6987c38` have S locks on page `5:1:86733` and they waits for an S lock on `5:1:89158`. But page `5:1:89158` is already locked by `process2f6c9e928`. This process has an SIX lock on this page. S (existing) and IX (requested) locks are incompatible (see bellow compatibility matrix).

Because of these incompatible locks (SIX vs S, S vs. IX) you get this deadlock.

Compatibility matrix of S, SIX and IX locks: (see [Lock compatibility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186396(v=sql.105).aspx))

```
                Existing granted mode
Requested mode  S        SIX    IX
S               [Yes]    [No]   No
SIX             No       No     No
IX              [No]     No     Yes
```

Now, your question

> Can a Shared Lock Wait for a Shared Lock to complete?

refers (I think) to this section of deadlock graph event:

```
  <owner-list>
    <owner id="process2f64a3868" mode="S" requestType="wait" />
  </owner-list>
  <waiter-list>
    <waiter id="process2f6986cf8" mode="S" requestType="wait" />
  </waiter-list>
```

Point of view: even if one process is the *"owner"* and the second process is the waiter I think both processes wait (`requestType="wait"`). So, there is no incompatibility between S locks. You can see from compatibility matrix that an S lock is compatible with another S lock.

Point of view: you should focus your attention first on why some processes (68, f8, 38) try to lock using a S lock an entire page. Maybe, are you using `REPEATABLE READ` isolation level and the execution plans that cause S locks on pages have {Table | [Clustered] Index} Scan operators ?

Comment: Just a small question, I am aware about every lock. But SIX is confusing me. Can you please explain a little using the above example?

Comment: For your question, Actually one of my background process is doing a bulk upload. The reason why processes (68, f8, 38) is reading a page is because I am doing paging(web page) and process 28 is the bulk upload.

Comment: SIX and IX locks are described [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175519(v=sql.105).aspx). Above example: it's possible that SQL Server wants to convert an existing SIX lock on page 5:1:86733 to IX (see `<waiter id="process2f6c9e928" mode="IX" requestType="convert" />`).

Comment: Which Tool you used to design this?

Comment: It's a tool to create diagrams: Concept Draw